# Spacing after automatic linebreaks in tables

Tags: tables, line-breaking, line-spacing

when formatting my tables I noticed that the line spacing gets messed up after automatic line breaks: The space below that line is shrinked (which is most obvious if there is superscript). Is this a common problem? Please note that I want to keep the `longtabu` environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}           
\usepackage{longtable, tabu}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}[H]{|X|X|l|}
   \hline
   Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
   \hline
   Something && \\
   Something && \\
   Something with a really long name that enforces a linebreak && \\
   Something && \\
   Something with a really long name that enforces a linebreak && \\
   Something\textsuperscript{whatever} && \\
   Something && \\
   Something && \\
   \hline
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: you said you want to keep tabu but it looks like a tabu feature, the line spacing is more even with `\begin{longtable}{|p{6cm}|p{6cm}|l|}` (I don't think `longtabu` has an `H` option)

Comment: I really want to keep `longtabu´ as it elegantly solves a lot of other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, if this modification of your MWE gives what you looking for:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable, tabu}

\begin{document}    
{\tabulinesep =_3pt^3pt % <-- added
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {|X|X|l|}
   \hline
   Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
   \hline
   Something && \\
   Something && \\
   Something with a really long name that enforces a linebreak && \\
   Something && \\
   Something with a really long name that enforces a linebreak && \\
   Something\textsuperscript{whatever} && \\
   Something && \\
   Something && \\
   \hline
\end{longtabu}  
  }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Zarko! It's not perfect but I think it will do. Otherwise I really might need to thick about switching to `longtable`.

Comment: @Anne, try to increase verticals space above and bellow table rows, for example `\tabulinesep =_5pt^5pt`. Maybe result be better then now. Unfortunately `tabu` package is quite buggy and not maintained anymore. this is pity.